Continuous spectrum of an operator $l^1$ to $l^1$
A linear operator $T: ℓ^1 → ℓ^1$ is defined by
$$
T(x_1, x_2, x_3, …)= (y_1, y_2, y_3, …), \\
\text { where } y_k=\frac{k+1}{k}x_{k+1}   \text { for } k ⩾ 1 .
$$
I want to compute $σ_c(T)$.

To compute $\|T\|$:
$$\|Tx\|_1=
\sum_{k=1}^∞|y_k|=
\sum_{k=1}^∞
\frac{k+1}k{|x_{k+1}|}
≤2\sum_{k=1}^∞{|x_{k+1}|}
≤2\sum_{k=1}^∞{|x_k|}
=2\|x\|_1$$
equality holds when $x=e_2$. So ${‖T‖}=2$.

By induction, I obtain an explicit formula for $T^n x$:
$$(T^nx)_k=\frac{k+n}kx_{k+n}\text { for } k ⩾ 1 .$$
so
\begin{align*}‖T^nx‖_1&=\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{k+n}k|x_{k+n}|\\&≤(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^∞|x_{k+n}|\\&≤(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^∞|x_k|=(n+1)‖x‖_1\end{align*}
equality holds when $x=e_{n+1}$. So $\|T^n\|=n+1$.

To compute the eigenvalues:
$$λ∈σ_p(T)⇒∃x∈ℓ^1:x_1=1,Tx=λx\\⇒λx_k=\frac{k+1}kx_{k+1}\\⇒x_k=\frac{λ^{k-1}}k\\⇒‖x‖_1=\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{|λ|^{k-1}}k<\infty⇒|λ|<1$$
For $|λ|<1$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{|λ|^k}k=-\log(1-|λ|)$, so $x∈ℓ^1$, so $λ∈σ_p$.
so $σ_p(T)={\rm D}(0,1)$.

To compute the spectrum of $T$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|T^n\right\|^{1\over n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{1\over n}=1$$
by Gelfand's formula $σ(T)⊆\overline{\rm D}(0,1)$.
$σ(T)⊇σ_p(T)={\rm D}(0,1)$, but $σ(T)$ is closed, so $σ(T)⊇\overline{\rm D}(0,1)$, so $σ(T)=\overline{\rm D}(0,1)$.
so $σ_c(T)\amalgσ_r(T)=σ(T)\setminus σ_p(T)=S^1$
Then how to compute $σ_c(T)$?
I know that

The dual of $c_0$ is $ℓ^1$; the dual of $ℓ^1$ is $ℓ^∞$.

Is the following true?

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T \in \mathscr{L}(X)$.  If $\lambda$ is
in the residual spectrum of $T$, then $\lambda$ is in the point spectrum of $T'$.

I think $T':ℓ^∞→ℓ^∞$ is
$$T'(x_1, x_2, x_3, …)= (0, y_2, y_3, …), \\
\text{ where } y_{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{k}x_k   \text{ for } k ⩾ 1 .$$
$\sigma_p(T')=\{0\}$, so $\sigma_r(T)=\emptyset$, so $\sigma_c(T)=S^1$. Is this correct?

If the range of $A$ is not dense, then by the Hahn-Banach theorem there is a nonzero bounded linear functional on $X$ which vanishes on $A(X).$ Thus your claim that "if $\lambda\in \sigma_r(T)$ then $\lambda\in \sigma_p(T'),$" holds.

@RyszardSzwarc Thanks. So my problem is solved.
